# Dictionary new object as TValue

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

The Dictionary signature looks like :

```
Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
```

Is it possible, somehow, to instantiate a new object as `TValue` ?

I know I can call a method from there or the `new` keyword but I can't have parameters there and the object I wish to instantiate needs parameters.

Comment: In what context do you have a dictionary where you don't know the value type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there's no restriction that `TValue` be a class or have a constructor, there's no safe way to "create" an instance (it's possible that `TValue` is a type that does not have a public constructor!)

One option is to use [`default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx):

```
var value = default(TValue);
```

which will return `null` for reference types, `0` for numeric types, or a struct with each member initialized to it's default.

You can also *inherit* from `Dictionary` and add the restriction that `TValue` have a default constructor:

```
public class MyDict<TKey,TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> where TValue : new()
{
    public void Add(TKey key)
    {
       this.Add(key, new TValue());
    }
}
```

or add the restriction in an extension method:

```
public static class Ext
{
   public static void Add<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> d, TKey key) where TValue : new()
    {
        d.Add(key, new TValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with your point on the dictionary having no restriction on its type arguments, but `TValue` might have restriction depending on the context in which it is used (since you can't instantiate a dictionary with unresolvable type arguments). If you use it in a function that has a generic argument with (for example) `class, new()` as a restriction and the same type is used in the `TValue` argument, then you can do a `new TValue()`. But to the point of the original questions, there is no type arguments restriction that implies a certain constructor with defined arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not clarified the context, I imagined a class with an internal `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` storage and a factory method taking arbitrary number of arguments:

```
public class Beings<TValue>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<long, TValue> dictionary;
    private readonly Func<object[], TValue> giveBirth;

    public Beings(Func<object[], TValue> giveBirth)
    {
        this.dictionary = new Dictionary<long, TValue>();
        this.giveBirth = giveBirth;
    }

    public TValue Create(params object[] args)
    {
        var newBeing = this.giveBirth(args);
        this.dictionary[this.dictionary.Count] = newBeing;

        return newBeing;
    }
}
```

Note that it's constructor takes a `Func<object[], TValue>` delegate - any objects in, TValue out.

Next imagine two cases of beings: Humans and Human Clones. Humans usually have mom and dad, Clones have only the original Human. Thus we have the classes like:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Name}")]
public class Human
{
    public Human(string name, Human mom, Human dad)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Mom = mom;
        this.Dad = dad;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Human Mom { get; private set; }
    public Human Dad { get; private set; }
}

public class HumanClone : Human
{
    public HumanClone(Human original)
        : base(original.Name + "_Clone", null, null)
    {
        this.Original = original;
    }

    public Human Original { get; private set; }
}
```

And now we segregate our living species by `Beings<Human>` and `Beings<HumanClone>`, creating factory delegates with `Func<object[], TValue>` signatures:

```
Func<object[], Human> humanGiveBirth = humanBirthArgs =>
    new Human(name: (string)humanBirthArgs[0], mom: (Human)humanBirthArgs[1], dad: (Human)humanBirthArgs[2]);

var humans = new Beings<Human>(humanGiveBirth);
```

and

```
Func<object[], HumanClone> humanCloneGiveBirth = humanCloneBirthArgs =>
    new HumanClone(original: (Human)humanCloneBirthArgs[0]);

var humanClones = new Beings<HumanClone>(humanCloneGiveBirth);
```

And to test our universe we create some species:

```
var human1 = humans.Create("Adam", null, null);
var human2 = humans.Create("Eva", null, null);
var human3 = humans.Create("Kain", human2, human1);
var human4 = humans.Create("Avel", human2, human1);

var humanClone1 = humanClones.Create(human1);
var humanClone2 = humanClones.Create(human2);
```

The drawbacks is that you do not have intellisense for constructor parameters, also you have to explicitly type cast each object arg in your factory delegate definition.
May be you could prettify some things with `Delegate.CreateDelegate` and Reflection magic...

**UPDATE:**

But the more I think about it, the more artificial the code looks... I used `TValue Create(params object[] args)`, but I might just as well introduce `TValue Create(Func<TValue> giveBirth)` and use it like

```
var human = humans.Create(() => new Human("Elvis", elvisMom, elvisDad));
```

And all the purpose of Create method would be to just inject the delegate call where it likes (inside some lock, for example) - like it is done in [ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)